# How to get all Objects from a List in a List with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List of Cars and they have a List in them with their Production Factories.

```
List<Car> cars = new List();
```

Now I have in this list the Factorys where each car is in Production.

```
List<FactoryCollection> factoryCollections = cars
    .Select(c => c.Factories)
    .ToList();
```

and now i want to get a List with the single Factories so that i have all Factories where the Specific Cars are in Production.

For Example:

```
List<Factory> factories = factoryCollections
    .Select(f => f.Werk);
```

My Problem is that the Objects are one level deeper.

**My Question is:**

How to get the Objects with a LINQ statement or is there a more easy way to get on all the Factories ?

Comment: You can flatten a hierarchy with `SelectMany()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `SelectMany` instead of `Select`

```
List<Factory> factories = Car.Select(x => x.Factories).SelectMany(y => y.Werk).ToList();
```

Answer (score 5):

It seems, that you're looking for `SelectMany`:

```
  List<Car> Car = new List<Car>() {... }
  ...
  var factories = Car
    .Where(car => IsCarSpecific(car))
    .SelectMany(car => car.Factories
       .Select(factory => factory.Werk));
    // .Distinct(); // in case you want distinct factories
    // .ToList(); if you want materiazlize into List<Factory>
```

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for `SelectMany`, but as opposed to other answers somewhat nested:

```
List<Factory> factories = cars
    .SelectMany(c => c.Factories.Select(f => f.Werk)) 
    .ToList();
```